# How can I make command line arguments visible to Flask routes?

Tags: python, flask

I am using Flask to build a tool to view data locally in a browser. I want to pass the directory containing the data as a command line argument, and then pass it to the appropriate routing function to do the rendering.

This does what I want, but with global variables:

```
dataDir = None

def initializeData(pathname):
    global dataDir
    dataDir = pathname

@app.route('/')
def home():
    # Use dataDir as desired

if __name__ == '__main__':
    initializeData(sys.argv[1])
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.run()
```

Is there a better way to communicate between the command line and my routes?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your flask app has a `config` property. Also, this code will fail with a NameError. You want something like this:

```
import sys
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return 'You wanted {!r} directory'.format(app.config.get('some_setting'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.config['some_setting'] = sys.argv[1]
    app.run()
```

Comment: Right you are - fixed!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `app.config.from_json('config.json')` so that you can configure your env parameters in a json file.

Comment: `from_json` was [removed in 2.1.0](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/changes/?highlight=from_json#version-2-1-0) and replaced with [from_file](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/?highlight=from_file#flask.Config.from_file) which supports json and toml, e.g. `app.config.from_file("config.json", load=json.load)` or `app.config.from_file("config.toml", load=toml.load)`

Comment: Note that this requires settings in the config file to be uppercase. From the docs, `from_file` passes the loaded mapping to [from_mapping](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/?highlight=from_file#flask.Config.from_mapping), which states _"Updates the config ... ignoring items with non-upper keys."_