# How to pass an arbitrary argument to Flask through app.run()?

Tags: python, flask

I would like to pass an object to a newly initiated flask app. I tried following the solution from the question: [how-can-i-make-command-line-arguments-visible-to-flask-routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41264425/how-can-i-make-command-line-arguments-visible-to-flask-routes)

**Edit**

I would like to take a value that I pick up from initiating the python script from the command line.

ie.

```
$ run python flaskTest.py -a goo
```

I am not seeing the difference between this and the solution to the question I am trying to replicate.
**Edit**

Thus, I tried the following:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

print('Passed item: ', app.config.get('foo'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  from argparse import ArgumentParser

  parser = ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument('-a')
  args = parser.parse_args()
  val = args.a

  app.config['foo'] = val
  app.run()
```

Hoping to get the result...

```
'Passed item: Goo'
```

Is there a method for passing an arbitrary object through the initialization with app.run()?

Comment: So when you say an object, you mean an actual python object as of a instance of a class ?

Comment: In this example trying to pass something simple such as string from the command line.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well the script is executing from top to bottom, so you can't print something you don't have yet. Putting the print statement inside a classic flask factory function allow you to first parse command line, then get your object and then use it:

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app(foo):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['foo'] = foo
    print('Passed item: ', app.config['foo'])
    return app

if __name__ == '__main__':
  from argparse import ArgumentParser
  parser = ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument('-a')
  args = parser.parse_args()
  foo = args.a
  app = create_app(foo)
  app.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

So, the problem is that you're trying to access the value *before* you define it. You would need to do something like this in your case:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['foo'] = 'Goo'

print('Passed item: ', app.config['foo'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run()
```

If you're trying to access that value while loading some third module, you'll need to define the value somewhere ahead of time.

Answer (score -1):

An update for more recent versions of Flask: when running through `flask run` you can now invoke an app factory and even pass arguments ([docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/cli/#application-discovery)).

Example code:

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app(foo=None):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config["foo"] = foo
    return app

# if __name__ == "__main__": ... not necessary
```

Assuming it is saved as `flaskTest.py`, you can run it using:

```
export FLASK_APP="flaskTest:create_app('value of foo')"
flask run
```

Comment: Could you please give an example of how to run it when deployed to an url?

Comment: It depends on where and how it is deployed. If you somehow have a Python script calling/instantiating your Flask app (e.g. a .wsgi file on Apache+mod_wsgi) you call your factory function from the script and is easy to pass arguments. In other situations (e.g. using gunicorn, uwsgi or similar) try looking at the relevant documentation.