# Flask run with argument

Tags: python, flask

I have a simple single page flask web page. This app requires a cmd line argument during run as follow: `python3 example.py home/dir1/dir2`.
Now I want to run this app using `flask run` command. I set `FLASK_APP=example.py` then executing `flask run` command will start the flask server but since I am not able to provide the argument, my app will not work. How can I pass this `home/dir1/dir2` argument with `flask run`? I've used argv for the argument instead of argparse.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make command line arguments visible to Flask routes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41264425/how-can-i-make-command-line-arguments-visible-to-flask-routes)

Comment: I saw this answer before asking. first of all I was confused about app.config['some settings']. What should I put here. Secondly, how it gonna help me to provide argument like: flask app <my argument>? if I use python3 example.py <my argument>, then it works. So, my question is not passing argument to flask, question is passing argument while running with flask run.

Comment: took me awhile to figure out too haha.. hope the answer helps you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `flask --help` I saw you can pass arguments to the app from the command line like this:

```
flask --app 'example:create_app("argument to the app!", 5)' run
```

To do that you have to have a file called `example.py` which has a method `create_app` which inits the app, something like this:

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app(arg1, arg2):
    """Create and configure an instance of the Flask application."""
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route("/hello")
    def hello():
        return "Hello, World!"

    app.add_url_rule("/", endpoint="index")

    print(arg1)  # Prints "argument to the app!"
    print(arg2)  # Prints "5"

    return app
```

Other option you have is using environment variables, for example in the shell do

```
export CMD_ARG=56
```

and you can access that in the app with

```
import os
cmd_arg = os.environ["CMD_ARG"]  # "56"
```

In the `flask --help` they also have an option `-e` to pass in environment variables from a file.

Comment: Thank you for the environment variable idea.